# Passing Props in SolidJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solid-js

I came across something weird while trying to pass props in SolidJS. I've created a store using createStore which I pass through the component tree using `Context.Provider`. I also have the helper function `useStore` which lets me access the store anywhere in the component tree (I'm experimenting with React design patterns in SolidJS). I have two components `Anime.jsx` (parent) and `EpisodeList.jsx` (child). I'm fetching data when the `Anime` component mounts and then populate the `store` with the setter provided by `createStore`.After which I pass the fetched data to `EpisodeList`. However, accessing the props of `EpisodeList` returns an empty proxy (Not sure why, but I think the `EpisodeList` component isn't re-rendered when store is updated with store.currentAnimeData). I've attached the output below of the console.log statements below.

Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

```
###################################
# Anime.jsx (Parent component)
###################################
const Anime = (props) => {
  const [store, setStore] = useStore();

  const getAnimeData = async () => {
    const currentAnimeId = store.currentAnime.animeId;
    const currentAnimeData = await firebase.getAnimeData(currentAnimeId);
    setStore(
      produce((store) => {
        store.currentAnimeData = currentAnimeData;
      })
    );
  };

  onMount(() => {
    getAnimeData();
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className={css`
          width: 100%;
          min-height: 20px;
          margin: 8px 0px 5px 0px;
          padding: 0px 10px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          font-size: 20px;
          word-wrap: break-word;
          line-height: 1;
        `}
      >
        <span
          className={css`
            font-size: 20px;
            color: #e32451;
          `}
        >
          {"Watching: "}
        </span>
        {store.currentAnime.name}
      </div>
      <Search></Search>
      <EpisodeList animeData={store.currentAnimeData.episodes} />
    </>
  );
};

#####################################
# EpisodeList.jsx (child component)
#####################################

const EpisodeList = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  console.log(props.animeData);

  ...... # UI stuff

  return (
    <div
      className={css`
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        margin-top: 10px;
      `}
    >
      <ScrollActionUp onmousedown={[scroll, true]} onmouseup={onmouseup}>
        ➭
      </ScrollActionUp>
      <div
        className={css`
          width: 100%;
          height: 432px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
          overflow: hidden;
        `}
        ref={scrollRef}
      >
        <For each={animeData.episodes}>
          {(episode, index) => {
            return (
              <Episode status={episode.watched} episode={episode}></Episode>
            );
          }}
        </For>
      </div>
      <ScrollActionDown onmousedown={[scroll, false]} onmouseup={onmouseup}>
        ➭
      </ScrollActionDown>
    </div>
  );
};

###############
# store.jsx
###############
import { createContext, createSignal, useContext } from "solid-js";
import { createStore } from "solid-js/store";

const StoreContext = createContext();

export function ContextProvider(props) {
  const [store, setStore] = createStore({});

  return (
    <StoreContext.Provider value={[store, setStore]}>
      {props.children}
    </StoreContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useStore() {
  return useContext(StoreContext);
}
```

[image: Console output]

Comment: It's not clear where you are logging this data, it is expected that it should start out empty. Is the log at the top level of a component (or in an effect but not accessing any properties on the store)? There could be many reasons this appears not to be working. Do you mind adding more code, or creating a repro at the solidjs playground? (EDIT: I just realized the logs are from those logs at the top of the component, which is what I suggested might be the problem. Components only ever run once).

Comment: Thanks for your comment it really helped. I was able to figure out what's happening. I guess thinking purely in terms of React is not applicable in every scenario (which I should've realized sooner).  Turns out the right data was always passed to the child component, it's just that I wasn't querying it properly and trying to debug with React in mind, thinking that the component should re-render everytime its props change. SolidJS in that sense is quite different. 

Thanks again for your insights. This bug was driving me crazy!

Comment: Sure! Glad to help. Solid's execution model really is very different than react, and unfortunately the constant comparisons of the two causes people first learning solid to forget that all the time. If you haven't tried the official solidjs tutorial, I'd recommend it, though there's also ongoing work to completely revamp the docs to help people get started with solid.